# Updating data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using editing file for updating data of mobile no, email details etc, but it is not updating , it shows the results of data so connection is working but no updating of data is there. code:

```
<?php

    include('header.php');
    $msg='';

     ?> 


<div class="page-cont1">                        
<!--heading starts-->

<?php

    session_start(); //starts the session
    if($_SESSION['user']){ //checks if user is logged in
    }
    else{
        header("location:index.php"); // redirects if user is not logged in
    }
    $user = $_SESSION['user']; //assigns user value
    $id_exists = false;
    ?>
    <body>
        <h2>Home Page</h2>
        <p>Hello <?php Print "$user"?>!</p> <!--Displays user's name-->
        <a href="logout.php">Click here to logout</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="home.php">Return to Home page</a>
        <h2 align="center">Currently Selected</h2>
        <table border="1px" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>E-Mail</th>
                <th>Mobile No</th>
                <th>Details</th>
                <th>Extra Information</th>

            </tr>
            <?php

                if(!empty($_GET['id']))
                {
                    $id = $_GET['id'];
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                    $id_exists = true;

                    $query = mysql_query("Select * from doctor Where id='$id'"); // SQL Query
                    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if($count > 0)
                    {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                            Print "<tr>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['id'] . "</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['your_email'] . "</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['mobile_no'] . "</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['detail'] . "</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['info'] . "</td>";

                            Print "</tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $id_exists = false;
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <?php

        if($id_exists)
        {
        Print '
        <form action="edit.php" method="POST">
            Enter new E-Mail: <input type="text" name="your_email"/><br/>
            Enter new Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile_no"/><br/>
            Enter new detail: <input type="text" name="detail"/><br/>
            Enter new Extra Information: <input type="text" name="info"/><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="Update List"/>
        </form>
        ';
        }
        else
        {
            Print '<h2 align="center">There is no data to be edited.</h2>';
        }
        ?>


<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {

        $field_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['your_email']);
        $field_phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile_no']);
        $detail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['detail']);
        $field_message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['info']);

        mysql_query("UPDATE doctor SET your_email='$field_email', mobile_no='$field_phone', detail='$detail', info='$field_message' WHERE id='$id'") ;
        header("location: home.php");
    }
?>
<?php
    include('footer.php');
    $msg='';

     ?> 

</body>
```

More over header file includes the connect file, and one query form  is there problem lie in header file or problem in edit file.

Comment: in the select query your table name is `doctor` in the update it´s `DOCTOR`! Tablenames are case-sensitive. Besides that do you have any error-messages? From mysql? From php?

Comment: I have used before    doctor  in spite of   DOCTOR  .  nothing happens   there is  no message sir ji

Comment: but one of them is definitely wrong. Since you get the data from the select, that version (lowercase) seems to be the right one...

Comment: It is fetching data but not replacing

Comment: YES. still - there is only ONE right spelling of one table, no matter in what case (select, update, insert, ...). If one spelling is working, the otherone is not....

Comment: as @Jeff suggested, why not got to phpmyadmin and check the right spelling and correct your script, no matter if its fixes your current problem or not? You have an error there, you need to fix it no matter it solves your current problem or not.

Comment: Please don't correct the errors in your initial question, because then future visitors cannot follow the answers anymore.

Comment: echo the sql generated and see what is wrong. do you have the table id to update or not in sql generated.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving ans i studied my code in the ans i read about ID  so i noticed that in updating there is no ID reference so i changed my code now problem solved  my working code is:

```
<?php

    include('header.php');
    $msg='';

     ?> 


<div class="page-cont1">                        
<!--heading starts-->

<?php

    session_start(); //starts the session
    if($_SESSION['user']){ //checks if user is logged in
    }
    else{
        header("location:index.php"); // redirects if user is not logged in
    }
    $user = $_SESSION['user']; //assigns user value
    $id_exists = false;
    ?>
    <body>
        <h2>Home Page</h2>
        <p>Hello <?php Print "$user"?>!</p> <!--Displays user's name-->
        <a href="logout.php">Click here to logout</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="home.php">Return to Home page</a>
        <h2 align="center">Currently Selected</h2>
        <table border="1px" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>E-Mail</th>
                <th>Mobile No</th>
                <th>Details</th>
                <th>Extra Information</th>

            </tr>
            <?php

                if(!empty($_GET['id']))
                {
                    $id = $_GET['id'];
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                    $id_exists = true;

                    $query = mysql_query("Select * from doctor Where id='$id'"); // SQL Query
                    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if($count > 0)
                    {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                            Print "<tr>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['id'] . "</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['your_email'] . "</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['mobile_no'] . "</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['detail'] . "</td>";
                                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['info'] . "</td>";

                            Print "</tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $id_exists = false;
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <?php

        if($id_exists)
        {
        Print '
        <form action="edit.php" method="POST">
            Enter new E-Mail: <input type="text" name="your_email"/><br/><br/>
            Enter new Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile_no"/><br/><br/>
            Enter new detail: <textarea name="detail" rows="6" id="detail" style="width:200px;"></textarea><br/><br/>
            Enter new Extra Information: <textarea name="info" rows="4" id="info" style="width:200px;"></textarea><br/><br/>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'">

            <input type="submit" value="Update List"/>
        </form>
        ';
        }
        else
        {
            Print '<h2 align="center">There is no data to be edited.</h2>';
        }
        ?>


<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {

        $field_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['your_email']);
        $field_phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile_no']);
        $detail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['detail']);
        $field_message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['info']);
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE doctor SET your_email='$field_email', mobile_no='$field_phone', detail='$detail', info='$field_message' WHERE id='$id'") ;
        header("location: home.php");
    }
?>
<?php
    include('footer.php');
    $msg='';

     ?> 

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First replace DOCTOR with doctor in update query (as Utharsh has stated).

Second:

You'll have to include the id in your form to be posted.

```
    Print '<form action="edit.php" method="POST">
        Enter new E-Mail: <input type="text" name="your_email"/><br/>
        Enter new Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile_no"/><br/>
        Enter new detail: <input type="text" name="detail"/><br/>
        Enter new Extra Information: <input type="text" name="info"/><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'">
        <input type="submit" value="Update List"/>
    </form>';
```

Comment: Sir i have added but no change  same problem

Comment: then please follow the steps all the others have suggested (echo out sql, test in phpmyadmin). That will tell you if the error is in the Update query or somewhere else.

Comment: Well, you know how to `Print` or `echo` a variable (string). Then find out where you have a chance to run that sql directly to your mysql-database. Usually phpmyadmin comes along with a php server and a mysql-server. Where/How did you set up your database?

Comment: $field_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['your_email']);
  $field_phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile_no']);
  $detail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['detail']);
  $field_message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['info']);
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];
  mysql_query("UPDATE doctor SET your_email='$field_email', mobile_no='$field_phone', detail='$detail', info='$field_message' WHERE id='$id'") ;
  header("location: home.php");

Comment: now, that doesnt help.... do: `echo "UPDATE doctor SET your_email='$field_email', mobile_no='$field_phone', detail='$detail', info='$field_message' WHERE id='$id'";`  copy what is printed in your browser, paste it in phpmyadmin as simple sql or whereever you've created your database.

Answer (score 0):

replace `DOCTOR` with`doctor` in your update query.

If problem persists than try to hard code your query and execute it in phpmyadmin.

put a hidden field in your form with reference to the id as jeff stated

Comment: i have changed it  but no use  same problem